# PHP: Backtick failing to work with command

Tags: php, bash

I have a PHP script that retrieves 200 lines from a file by executing a command in Bash using backtick operators. Here's what the code looks like:

```
$endline = `(shell execution that returns a number here)`;
$line = $endline - "200";
$lines = "sed -n '".$line.", ".$endline." p' log.txt";

echo $lines;
$file = `$lines`;
echo $file;
```

This code returns `$lines` as `sed -n '1800, 2000 p' log.txt`, but `$file` doesn't return any results. When directly using `sed -n '1800, 2000 p' log.txt` in a Bash terminal, I get the expected results.

What is done incorrectly here? Do the `'` characters have to be escaped?

**Edit:** The shell script added a space after the number, therefore misreading it.

Comment: You aren't executing the command

Comment: @ColeJohnson The backticks do not count as executing the command?

Comment: Yes, the shell command *is* being executed. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Or rather, the code is at least correct for that to be happening *if* shell commands are allowed (not in safe mode, and shell_exec is not disabled)

Comment: So, as a sanity check, can you do `echo \`tail log.txt\`;` ?

Comment: The problem appears to be that I am getting the var `$endline` from a different shell execution. How would I fix that?

Comment: @hexacyanide Whoops. My mistake. I didn't know about the backticks. I was always using `shell(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it's `$eof` or that your path (`log.txt`) is not appropriate.

I copied and pasted your code, and it works with the following tweaks:

1. syntax error fixed (add `;` to `echo $lines`)
2. change `$eof` to `$endline` (though you may not need to if `$eof` is valid
3. ensure that `log.txt` was a valid path (this is most likely your error)

otherwise, it ran as expected.

The reason it would work in Bash but not in PHP is that their "working directory" is not necessarily the same.

Comment: Yeah that's a bunch of junk I forgot while posting this, the real code is different from this. I've done `ls -al` and such to confirm the file directory.

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to run shell commands? can you do `echo \`pwd\`;` ?

Comment: I do have permission, I've started processes and listed the directory contents with backticks. NOTE: fixed syntax errors in original post.

Comment: fwiw, I can copy/paste your code verbatim (only changing log.txt to a known-good path for me and the line-counts similarly) and it runs great on PHP 5.3.4 on OS X 10.6.7